# Execute command on remote machine using telnet in one line

Tags: ssh, scripts, telnet

I need to write a script to monitor wlan0 interface of my remote machine. I can do this by executing `iwconfig wlan0` repeatedly on remote machine. But how to login to that machine and execute this command via telnet. I can do this via ssh, but ssh takes time to login and it hangs if connection to remote machine drops in the middle of execution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of repeatedly invoking the ssh command, you could run ssh to repeatedly execute the command on the remote system and then parse and use the output locally.  Then you wouldn't have to keep running the ssh connection and putting up with the initial lag.

For example:

```
ssh remotehost "while [ "1" ] ; do iwconfig wlan0 ; sleep 1 ; done"
```

Or, you could use netcat to send the output on the remote system back to your machine.  For example, run this on the local machine:

```
nc -l 9999
```

Then on the remote machine:

```
while [ "1" ] ; do iwconfig wlan0 ; sleep 1 | nc localmachine 9999
```

Replace localmachine here with the host or ip of the machine that will be doing the "monitoring".

You could even pipe the output from nc reading that port into another command.

Closer to your actual question, you could do this on the remote system to act as a telnet "server":

```
while [ "1" ] ; do iwconfig wlan0 | nc -l 9999 ; done
```

Then you could do this to get the outupt:

```
telnet remotehost 9999
```

Comment: Doing ssh as you told creates a process on remote machine. I couldn't able to kill that from my local machine. Is there any way to kill that?

Comment: If you kill the ssh command it will kill the remote process.

Comment: nope i tried it. The remote process is not terminating even though ssh is killed.

Comment: Create a script with a unique name, put your command in that, invoke that from the ssh command, and use a second ssh command to kill that script, but then you're back to waiting around for the ssh handshake to finish in order to do the kill.  The second command would look like this: `ssh remotehost killall uniquely-named-iwconfig-calling-script.sh`

Comment: The very last entry of my "answer" is probably the closest to what you want.  While it does provide unauthenticated access to the output of the `iwconfig` command, that's all it provides.  And it's not using much in he way of resources while it's waiting for new connections.  Did you try that one, yet?

Comment: My remote machine uses arm cross compiler. I am having issues in installing netcat. I will try and update you soon.

Comment: I know I'm late in the game, but running `ssh -t` will create an interactive session so that when you `ctrl-c`, it will also kill the script